# Unable to install libmicrohttpd

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install a software package -> libmicrohttpd. However, when I try to install it, a different package agl-libmicrohttpd12 is being installed. Can somebody please tell me why this happens? Below is the snapshot of what is happening:
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output - [edit] your question to copy text into it.